# How can I exclude node_modules wherever this path occurs in find in path searches in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I created a scope that has !file[myproj]:*/node_modules//* and also tried !file[myproj]:*//node_modules//* to not include any subdirectories that is under node_modules i.e. not include any files in any of these :

- `/node_modules/*`
- `a/node_modules/*`
- `b/c/node_modules/*`
- `e/f/g/node_modules/*`
- `anything/preceding/the/folder/node_modules/*`

but the search still shows matches in the node_module files. What is the correct pattern to use?

Comment: Please check this thread: [WEB-25601](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25601) E.g. [comment=27-2443766](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25601#comment=27-2443766) and [comment=27-2452251](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25601#comment=27-2452251)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have faced the issue, because `node_modules` are only partially excluded - direct dependencies listed in `package.json` are added to **JavaScript libraries** and thus included.

To exclude `node_modules` completely, use **In Project** scope for searching.

JavaScript libraries are only included when using **Directory** scope with corresponding folder selected, or when using custom scope with explicit filters.

Note that excluding libraries from custom scope is a bit tricky... To make it work, you need to prefix your scope pattern with `file[your_project_name]:*/&&` to overwrite the default scope - see  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145142#comment=27-1156171 for explanation

Related feature request: [IDEA-103560](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103560)

Comment: THANK YOU! the prefix you suggested (`file[your_project_name]:*/&&`) works to exclude node_modules from Find In Path searches, which I couldn't figure out how to do with a custom scope. Commenting to help future searches.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Project Structure -> Excluded Folders probably what you need

Comment: I already have that set for the node_module folders they still show in the search results

Comment: @claya Please show your Find in Path screen -- what options are chosen etc (put it in actual question). Thing is: even if directory is excluded ... but you choose to search in specific folder .. then excluded folders will also be searched. I'm not sure of that's your case or not -- need to know more details.